# FireMonkey - Styled ComboBox

Tags: combobox, firemonkey

I'm trying to get a styled `Combobox` to look like this:

[image]

I right clicked the `ComboBox` and modified the `Custom Style` like this:

[image]

And I'm getting this:

[image]

I tried to add more rectangles to other objects from the `Style Editor`, but I couldn't succeed to make the styled `ComboBox` to look as I want.

Any suggestions will be strongly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try to expand the `Layout`?. That one might define the look of the arrow button.

Comment: @Hans. Yes. As I stated before, I tried all possible combinations, by adding a `tRectangle` and hoping this should work. By the way, adding a `tRectangle` to `ButtonStyle` object, obfuscates it, thus, it no more responds to the click event. It seems (as I found searching the `Web`), that is the underlying `tListBox` that I must style, but I do not know how to reach it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gray line around the control is defined by the `background` item and the button with the arrow is defined by `ButtonStyleObject` inside `Layout`.
Both are images that are looked up into an image, which is different for each platform or style that is loaded (the default image on Windows is called `Windows 10 Desktopstyle.png`).

When I define my own custom styles, I personally prefer to use vector based definitions, i.e. I would replace the two image controls with `tRectangle` controls and define the arrow symbol using a TShape (placed inside the rectangle replacing `ButtonStyleObject`).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I take it for correct. Still, there is a little issue: if you look close to the the `ComboBox` picture, you'll notice that still there is a surranding area with the same color as in the `button` area. How can I set this area to the same blue light color as in the inside rectangle?

Comment: Everything that is drawn by the Combobox is defined by the style, so you just need to find the element in the style that draws that color. I have not tried to style a combobox before, so I don't know what element you should change, but it should be easy to find out. Note however that an element in a style can refer to another style, i.e. it looks-up its colors from another style. This is the case when `StyleLookup` is set.